# Prove $\sin^2(x)<\sin(x^2)$ for $0<x<\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I'm trying to prove  $\sin^2(x)<\sin(x^2)$ for $0<x<\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Attempt: This is equivalent to showing $f(x)=\sin(x^2)-\sin^2(x) = \sin(x^2)-\left(\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}\right)>0$. Since $f(0)=0$, if we show $f$ is increasing we are done. $f'(x) = 2x\cos(x^2)-\sin(2x)$ but I can't see why it's greater than zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finishing ellya's proof: For $x>1$ we have
$$\sin^2(x)< \sin(x) < \sin(x^2)$$
Since $\sin(x)$ is increasing in our domain. For $x\le1$:
$$\cos(x^2)\ge\cos(x), x>\sin(x)\implies 2x\cos(x^2)>2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)$$

Comment: Nice and short :)

Comment: Where's $\sqrt{\frac\pi2}$ used? It certainly doesn't hold for all $x>1$.

Comment: @user2345215 It is used in the second inequality($\sin(x)<\sin(x^2) $), since $\sin x$ is increasing in that domain. I will include it.

Comment: @chubakueno: I know, but shouldn't that be mentioned in the answer? Oh ok, I'll delete these comments after you include it.

Comment: @user2345215 Don't worry, I think it will help someone later :)

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts at the moment are to take a step back from what you have put, and see that on $0\lt x\lt\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ , $\sin(x)\lt1$ so here $\sin^2(x)\lt\sin(x)$, now it is a question of showing that $\sin(x)\lt \sin(x^2)$

Comment: But that is not true for $x<1$. So we need a tighter estimate.

Comment: I believe it is since $\sin(x)$ is increasing on zero to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ so on $ 0$ to $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$, $\sin(x)\lt 1\Rightarrow \sin^2(x)\lt\sin(x)$.

Comment: Yes, your steps are right. But it is not strong enough, since I was saying that $\sin(x)<\sin(x^2)$ is not true for $x<1$.

Comment: But wait! This is useful :D That is true for $x>1$. And using that derivative we have to show that $2x\cos x^2>2\sin x\cos x$. Since $x>\sin x$, it is sufficient to show now that $\cos(x^2)>\cos x$. That is true for $x<1$ :). The case $x=1$ leads to equality.

Comment: ...no, it didn't lead to equality. But the proof still works (I think).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the brute force way:

$$\sin^2(x)<\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}\right)^2<x^2-\frac{(x^2)^3}{3!}<\sin(x^2)$$
for $0<x<\sqrt\frac{\pi}2$.

But it's not pretty to verify the middle inequality, although it's surely doable.

You can check it on [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3Cx%3Csqrt%28pi%2F2%29+%26%26+%28x-x%5E3%2F3%21%2Bx%5E5%2F5%21%29%5E2%3Cx%5E2-x%5E6%2F3%21) (solution).

Answer (score 1):

By using the Weierstrass product for the sine function,
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\prod_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2\pi^2}\right),$$
you have that proving:
$$\forall k\geq 1,\forall x\in(0,\pi/2),\qquad \left(1-\frac{x}{k^2\pi^2}\right)^2<\left(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2\pi^2}\right)\tag{1}$$
is enough. The RHS of $(1)$ is a concave function over $I=(0,\pi/2)$, so we have, for instance:
$$\forall x\in I,\qquad 1-\frac{x^2}{k^2\pi^2}>1-\frac{2x}{\pi k^2},$$
while the LHS of $(1)$ is a convex function over $I$. Since the values of the LHS and the RHS in $(1)$ agree for $x=0$, in order to prove $(1)$ we only need to prove:
$$\forall k\geq 1,\qquad \left(1-\frac{1}{2\pi k^2}\right)^2 < 1-\frac{1}{4k^2},$$
that is equivalent to:
$$\left(4-\frac{1}{\pi k^2}\right)>\pi.\tag{2}$$
Now $(2)$ is trivial since for any $k\geq 1$ we have $\frac{1}{\pi k^2}\leq\frac{1}{\pi}$ and $4-\frac{1}{\pi}>\pi$ holds.